# Manipulation of $C^1$ funcitons

Tags: analysis, self-learning

I think I read somewhere that composition of $C^1$ functions is also $C^1$, but I could not find the reference now. Also, is the difference of two $C^1$ functions still a $C^1$ function, please? And in general, what kind of algebraic manipulation of $C^1$ functions preserves the $C^1$ property, please? Thank you!

Comment: Are you considering $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ or more general $f: X \to Y$ between manifolds? Composition works for both, but addition, multiplication, etc don't (in general) for the second. Depends on having that kind of structure on $Y$.

Comment: @Fantini Thank you for your response. I am only considering Euclidean space, i.e. $\mathbb R^n$. Any reference for this, please?

Comment: I love Duistermaat's double team Multidimensional Real Analysis, but if you haven't studied analysis in one variable it's pretty tough. The idea is the same: in euclidean spaces, where you have vector space structure (a banach space) you can add, subtract, multiply and (for functions nonzero everywhere in their domain) divide. They need to be all defined, of course, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @Fantini Thanks, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) implies that the composition of $C^1$ functions is $C^1$. Note this applies to multivariable functions too. Consider $M(u,v)=uv$, the multiplication function, and $S(u,v)=u-v$, the subtraction function. These are $C^1$ smooth (they are polynomials after all). So, the composition of $x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ with $(u,v)\mapsto uv$ is also $C^1$; and this composition is nothing but the product $f(x)g(x)$.

When we get to division $D(u,v) = u/v$, things get interesting: this function is smooth only when $v\ne 0$. So, $f/g$ is guaranteed to be $C^1$ only in the region where $g\ne 0$. You can lose smoothness when dividing $C^1$ functions, even if the quotient is continuous: e.g., dividing 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3 \sin(1/x) \quad &x\ne 0\\ 0, \quad &x=0 \end{cases}$$
by $g(x)=x$ and extending to $0$ by continuity, we get 
$$f(x)/g(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin(1/x) \quad &x\ne 0\\ 0, \quad &x=0 \end{cases}$$
which is not $C^1$.

Summary: the multivariable chain rule essentially contains all rules for algebraic manipulation of functions that preserve smoothness. Taking the inverse (which isn't an algebraic manipulation) stands aside from it; this is what the Inverse Function theorem is for.

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation why the chain rule implies the composition of $C^1$ functions is $C^1$? This may be extremely obvious, although I don't see why it follows directly from the chain rule.